# How to bind and save td tag value in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to bind data from the controller by using the `ng-init = getNCandEmail()` function, it was success. Now I want to save the binded values. Anyone please suggest a solution. The Code is given below.

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group" ng-init="getNCandEmail()">

    <table class="table table-hover table-responsive" id="table">
        <tr style="background-color: #00bffa"> <td><b>The Following Non Conformance has been Added/Edited</b></td><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td>NC Number:</td><td ng-repeat="i in  ncDetail.MailList" ng-bind="i.IncidentID"></td></tr>
        <tr style="background-color: #b0c4de"><td>Incident Title:</td><td ng-repeat="i in  ncDetail.MailList">{{i.IncidentTitle}}</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Date&Time:</td><td ng-repeat="i in  ncDetail.MailList" >{{i.IncidentDate |jsonDate}}</td></tr>
        <tr style="background-color: #b0c4de"><td>Summary:</td><td ng-repeat="i in  ncDetail.MailList">{{i.Summary}}</td></tr>
        <tr><td>RemedialAction:</td><td ng-repeat="i in  ncDetail.MailList">{{i.RemedialAction}}</td></tr>
        <tr style="background-color: #b0c4de"><td>ExactLoc:</td><td ng-repeat="i in  ncDetail.MailList">{{i.ExactLoc}}</td></tr>
        <tr><td>CompletedDate:</td><td ng-repeat="i in  ncDetail.MailList">{{i.CompletedDate | jsonDate}}</td></tr>
     </table>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `<td ng-model="Your_value">`, `$scope.Your_value` will have the saved value.

Comment: @Arulkumar Now it works.Thanks a lot